# Assembly of C code is not understood?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, operating-system

I have written a simple c code in visual studio. Here is the code ..

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int global;
    int onemore=5;
    int main(){
        int local;
        static int slocal;
        return 0;
    }
```

and here is it's assembly after compiling in visual studio ..

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 

    TITLE   c:\Users\amit_bhaira\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AssOneQuestion1\AssOneQuestion1\question1.c
    .686P
    ->.XMM
    ->include listing.inc
    ->.model flat   

->INCLUDELIB MSVCRTD
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  _onemore
_DATA   SEGMENT
COMM    _global:DWORD
_onemore DD 05H
_DATA   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
->EXTRN__RTC_Shutdown:PROC
->EXTRN__RTC_InitBase:PROC
;   COMDAT rtc$TMZ
; File c:\users\amit_bhaira\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\assonequestion1\assonequestion1\question1.c
rtc$TMZ SEGMENT
->__RTC_Shutdown.rtc$TMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_Shutdown
rtc$TMZ ENDS
;   COMDAT rtc$IMZ
rtc$IMZ SEGMENT
__RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_InitBase
; Function compile flags: /Odtp /RTCsu /ZI
rtc$IMZ ENDS
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 4    : int main(){

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 204                ; 000000ccH
    ->push  ebx  
    ->push  esi
    ->push  edi //why these(ebx,esi and edi) registers are pushed into the stack ??  
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-204]
    mov ecx, 51                 ; 00000033H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd

; 5    :    int local;
; 6    :    ->static int slocal;  
; 7    :    return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 8    : }

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

I have put an arrow(->) in front of the lines that I didn't get. So please explain them.

Though I have taken a static variable inside the main method but no special steps are taken by the 
compiler, what is that suppose to mean. Static varialbe is also going to be handled like other local 
variable, no special storage for static variable. If Yes then how is the memory of static variable is preserved for the next function call ??

Comment: I think your `slocal` has been optimized out. The pushes correspond with the pops at the end, they serve as regular register save/restore.

Comment: It's unreferenced here. even if it wasn't optimized out, the function does nothing with it and isn't involved in its initialization.

Comment: it's not optimized out, i put slocal=5 and then tried, still same result, and what do you mean by ragular register save?? they must be doing it for some purpose right ??

Comment: @AmitBharia The static variable isn't located on the stack. It's located in the data segment. The value 5 will be placed in the proper location, so there's no need to run code to initialize your variable to 5, it will jsut be loaded from the .exe file into the data segment in memory.

Comment: If you initialize `slocal` it may still be optimized out, because it is not used. Try to return its value. If a function uses a register it may have to save its original value on entry of the function and restore it at the end. That is regular register save/restore.

Comment: @Nos i have pasted the whole assembly, could you please locate where compiler is doing so ??

Comment: @Bryan Olivier ahh !! so it's a convenction right ? :) got it and thanks. and let me try returing this variable also.

Comment: @BryanOlivier yeah you are right Bryan, it was an optimization .. i have tryied returning the variable and i got this in the data segment ..

"_DATA SEGMENT
COMM _global:DWORD
_onemore DD 05H
?slocal@?1??main@@9@9 DD 05H    ; `main'::`2'::slocal
_DATA ENDS"

Comment: please tell me a single reason, why this question has been marked negative ?

Comment: Wasn't me to downvote it, but I might say "because you claim you got the three `pop` at the end" ;-) The answer you're looking for is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561502.aspx in the section on "calling conventions"

Comment: Also, just to clarify here: The code above is unoptimized. With optimization on, the compiler doesn't create such _unnecessary_ load/store operations - your func would mostly be optimized out. I tend to try telling people that assembly code is actually _easier to read_ when created with optimization enabled, because there's less "gunk" in it ...

Comment: @FrankH. Thank you for the link .. and i am not blaming anyone for downvoting it.. but atleast he should have left a comment, so that i can improvise it next time .. :(

Comment: and yes optimization level of compiler is set to default, but still it optimized the code a bit, more specificaly the "slocal" variable, i don't know why?? :)

Comment: @AmitBhaira neither `local` not `slocal` are actually used in the code, so the compiler optimized them away. The remainder of the code is the (unoptimized) function pro/epilogue and the microsoft-specific code initializing the "stack canary" (that's the `0xcccccccc` pattern written into the stack frame). I don't know enough about the inner workings of MSVC to be able to say why it chooses to create a stackframe at all here; `gcc` will reduce the above code to `XOR EAX, EAX; RET` even at lowest optimization level.